# How interactive can a component be inside of a widget?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, widgetkit

my job is to create a few widgets using widgetkit and swiftui, however the main project is build on uikit so I am not very good with swiftUI. Nevertheless, I would like to know whether I can add a graph inside of, for example, medium sized widget, and can the graph be scrollable to reveal more information? Or could it only be clickable? Thank you.

I know how widgets work, just interested in whether it is possible to create a scrollable graph inside of a medium sized widget.

Comment: Widgets are like gifs with "tappable areas" https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=yv6so7ie

Comment: Thank you, this link will be very useful for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only just getting started with widgets myself, so happy to be corrected. But interactivity with widgets is very limited - effectively to taps and nothing else. They're designed more to be informational displays than interactive user interfaces.

If your widget is larger than the small size (the square one that takes up the same space as 2x2 app icons on the iPhone home screen), you can have multiple tap targets. For example, if your widget had a list of calendar items, you could set it up so that a user tapping on a specific item opened the app with a view showing that item in more detail.

So no, a scrollable graph isn't feasible. But what you can do is create a graph that shows a snapshot of data that a user is most likely to find useful when glancing at their home screen – and making sure that if they tap on it, they go straight through to a more interactive version of the same data.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful information for me.